# Firebase Cloud Functions Circular Crops with ImageMagick

Tags: firebase, imagemagick, google-cloud-functions

I am struggling creating a firebase cloud function that takes a user uploaded image to firebase storage and doing a circular crop on it with Imagemagick. I've tried my best to take the example from [here](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/blob/master/convert-images/functions/index.js) and [here](http://ryanbrooks.co.uk/posts/2015-09-05-imagemagick-circular-avatars/) to make it happen but no dice. Please, any help will be greatly accepted! Thank you!

Comment: What does not work or what is happening? What version of Imagemagick do you have? What actual code have you used for the imagemagick part? Are you getting any errors?

Comment: Is your issue with the imagemagick commands or with firebase?

Comment: This is the command I am using:

`convert "/tmp/thumb_tekken_9-wallpaper-1280x800.jpg" -alpha set ( +clone -distort DePolar 0 -virtual-pixel HorizontalTile -background None -distort Polar 0 ) -compose Dst_In -composite -trim +repage "/tmp/thumb_tekken_9-wallpaper-1280x800.jpg`

The error I get is:

`Syntax error: "(" unexpected`

Comment: How did you use this command in Cloud functions? With this syntax?

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work by removing the parenthesis...